# Random pixels appearing in console window

Tags: c, windows

I am writing a C Windows console application and strange pixels sometimes apper on the screen.

More specifically, the application writes and deletes characters in different colors on the screen, and sometimes it appears to not be able to delete them completely, instead leaving a single pixel behind.

The function which I use exclusively to print is:

```
STATIC
STATUS
PositionPrint(
    __in    COORD           tPosition,
    __in    WORD            wColorAttributes,
    __in    TCHAR           cChar
    )
{
    SNOWFLAKE__STATUS   eRetval         =   STATUS_INVALID;
    BOOL                bConsoleRetval  =   FALSE;

    bConsoleRetval = SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), tPosition);
    RETVAL_CHECK(
        bConsoleRetval,
        STATUS_SET_CONSOLE_CURSOR_POSITION_FAILED,
        "SetConsoleCursorPosition failed"
    );

    bConsoleRetval = SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), wColorAttributes);
    RETVAL_CHECK(
        bConsoleRetval,
        STATUS_SET_CONSOLE_TEXT_ATTRIBUTES_FAILED,
        "SetConsoleTextAttribute failed"
    );

    _tcprintf(_T("%c"), cChar);
lblCleanup:
    return eRetval;
}
```

The RETVAL_CHECK macro (just in case):

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define DEBUG_PRINT(message) (printf("%s %d %s %d %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, GetLastError(), (message)))
#else
#define DEBUG_PRINT(message)
#endif

#define RETVAL_CHECK(_condition, _error, _message)   \
do                                                   \
{                                                    \
    if (!(_condition))                               \
    {                                                \
        eRetval = (_error);                          \
        DEBUG_PRINT(_message);                       \
        goto lblCleanup;                             \
    }                                                \
} while (0,0)
```

To delete a character, I just print a space in the same location.

I have windows 10 on my computer.

Does anyone have any idea what causes the problem or how to fix it?

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of these mysterious pixels?

Comment: This sort of thing is often the side-effect of undefined behaviour elsewhere, such as writing outside an array. It is unlikely these console functions will have random behaviour themselves.

Comment: There are too small for capturing and uploading.
It's just single, floating pixel, usually where a letter used to be.
I also noticed the pixels can disappear by themselves

Comment: Your description strongly indicates your code has some undefined behavior.  Suggest using a debugger and stepping through the code,

Comment: regarding this line: `while (0,0)`  It is wrong, the `while()` statement only has a single parameter.   We now wonder, what else is wrong with the code.

Comment: @user3629249 `while` is not a function - it's a valid, but useless, C statement.

Comment: Since you are working with *characters*, in a character based window, it's "just" a redrawing problem. That is, there is nothing in your code that plots or otherwise manipulates single pixels. On another computer or with other terminal settings (e.g., font size) this will not occur.

Comment: The `do ... while (0,0)` part is used to enforce addition of `;` after using the macro. I use `(0,0)` instead of `(0)` because I've been told that some compilers won't accept the latter.

Comment: `while()` is not a macro,  It is a regular C statement that takes one parameter (just like `for()` is a regular C statement that takes 3 parameters.    Writing `0,0`   says: evaluate the first 0 and throw the results away, then evaluate the second 0 and use its results for the 'condition' of the while statement,  BTW: it is poor programming practice to write a macro that looks like a function

Comment: @user3629249: You are confusing `operator,` with the comma used to delimit arguments passed to a function. `while` expects a single expression, and `0,0` is (it simply evaluates to `0`). The statement is thus perfectly legal, even if useless.

Comment: If using a variable width font, a space is usually narrower than most other characters.  So writing a space where some other char had been will not overlay all the pixels of the of the other char.   The best way to avoid that problem is to use a fixed width font.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was just a problem with my font.
I set my default CMD font to Courier New (for hebrew support).
Changing it back to Lucida Console seems to have solved the problem.